# Nested parent-child hover issue

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have multiple nested parent child elements. Now I am looking for the possible solution where on hover of any parent I want to change color of child which is only next to the parent.

```
<div class="parent">The Parent paragraph.
    <div  class="child">This is Child Para
        <div class="parent">The Parent paragraph.
            <div  class="child">This is Child Para
                <div class="parent">The parent paragraph.
                    <div  class="child">This is Child Para
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now as I said in code there is nested `parent` , `child` relationship. Now if you hover on first `parent` it should give effect to its associated `child` class only not to all the child classes.

CSS is :

```
div.parent:hover > .child:first-of-type {
    background: red;
}
```

I have even tried `first-of-type` but it's not working.

What changes in the css require to achieve that?

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6u4ff33/)**

Comment: In my opinion, you will need help of JavaScript in this case. Add a class on child while hover on parent and style with it.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. can you please explain your question.

Comment: The structure must be be of this form?

Comment: @Marian07 yes. Actually this is static just for example. But in my case it's dynamic upto n times.

Comment: First of type uses elements as a reference, not classes, so it will automatically reference to all `<div>`s instead of the `.child` class.

Comment: want this effect ? https://jsfiddle.net/x6u4ff33/1/

Comment: I've been playing around, but I cannot really seem to understand your *exact desired behavior*. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq Yes similar to mine. But slightly different.

Comment: Ok in this case u need to play with background color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with your current code in CSS, as this:

```
div.parent:hover > .child:first-of-type {
    background: red;
}
```

Is selecting all of this:

```
<div  class="child">This is Child Para
    <div class="parent">The Parent paragraph.
        <div  class="child">This is Child Para
            <div class="parent">The parent paragraph.
                <div  class="child">This is Child Para
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because all of it is inside the .child div. On the other hand, you can wrap the text you want to be red in a `<p>` or `<span>` and select that with the css instead, like this.

```css
p:hover + div > p {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>The Parent paragraph.</p>
  <div  class="child">
    <p>This is Child Para</p>
    <div class="parent">
      <p>The Parent paragraph.</p>
      <div  class="child">
        <p>This is Child Para</p>
        <div class="parent">
          <p>The Parent paragraph.</p>
          <div  class="child">
            <p>This is Child Para</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>This is second Para</div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/AquatuzMagnus/pen/ybrVaa)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to save changes.

Comment: It's fixed now.

Comment: @TheDictator The code is working now. I think I misunderstood what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

not perfect.

```css
div.parent>p:hover+.child:first-of-type>p {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>The Parent paragraph.</p>
  <div class="child">
    <p>This is Child Para</p>
    <div class="parent">
      <p>The Parent paragraph.</p>
      <div class="child">
        <p>This is Child Para</p>
        <div class="parent">
          <p>The parent paragraph.</p>
          <div class="child">
            <p>This is Child Para</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>This is second Para</div>
</div>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to pass default background to child element. bydefault all element inherit background from parent element.

```css
.child {
    background: white;
}
div.parent:hover > .child:first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">The Parent paragraph.
 <div  class="child">This is Child Para
     <div class="parent">The Parent paragraph.
   <div  class="child">This is Child Para
             <div class="parent">The parent paragraph.
     <div  class="child">This is Child Para
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>This is second Para</div>
</div>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: No change in the result. Still same.

Comment: for this you have to pass default background to `child` element. bydefault all element inharit background from parent element.

Comment: So that is what i want. I have statically bind it just to show it as Example. But actually in my case its dynamic.

Comment: you can pass default background color to all child element.

Comment: Using your code I got the answer. I haven't completely used it but somewhat it's similar to yours. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since inner parent and child divs are part of first child class, that is why its color is getting change.Once Try below code

```
<style>
div.parent:hover > .child {
    background: red;
}
.parent {
    background: none;
}
</style>
```

It will work properly when you hover on upper div to lower div, but if you hover lower to upper all previous div will change, because lowest div is part of all upper divs.